# List all float numbers in 1/d where d = range(1, 1000)

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to have a list of float numbers where the numerator is 1 and the denominator is `range(1, 1000)` my code only return a all zero list

```
x = list(range(1,1000))
aList = [1/d  for d in x]
print(aList)
```

Comment: You're doing a division of integer types. Please have a look at https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesnumeric.html

Comment: Check your version of python. That's Python 2 behavior.

Comment: There's no chance this will happen on Python3. Bill is right.

Answer (score 2):

The operation `1/d` performs integer division, not floating-point division.

Use `1.0/d` instead.